# python: comparing list of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

Just wondering the following:

```
print [()] == list(tuple()) # prints False
```

The first is a list containing an empty tuple, the second is an empty list.

Why this code prints False instead of True (same result in python 2 and 3)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because they don't produce the same result? The first is a list with 1 element, the second a list with zero elements. `list()` **converts an iterable to a list**. A tuple is an iterable, you *converted* an empty tuple to a list.

Answer (score 3):

You compared a list with one element (an empty tuple) with an empty list. `list(tuple())` does not do what you think it does.

That's because `list(object)` does **not** produce a list with that one object as an element. `list()` **converts** the object, which must be iterable, to a list. It copies the elements *out* of the object:

```
>>> dictionary = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> list(dictionary)  # iteration over a dictionary produces keys
['foo']
```

You gave it an empty tuple, so the result is an empty list:

```
>>> empty = ()
>>> list(empty)
[]
```

`tuple()` does the same thing, by the way. And both `list()` and `tuple()` *without an argument* produce an empty object.